# Replace loop with groupby for rolling daily calculation

Tags: python, pandas

How do I modify my code to have Pandas rolling daily reset each day?  Please see desired output below as this shows exactly what I am trying to achieve.

I think I may need to use groupby to get the same result but unsure how to progress.

**Data**

```
np.random.seed(5)
series = pd.Series(np.random.choice([1,3,5], 10), index = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2014-01-04', freq = '8h'))
series


2014-01-01 00:00:00    5
2014-01-01 08:00:00    3
2014-01-01 16:00:00    5
2014-01-02 00:00:00    5
2014-01-02 08:00:00    1
2014-01-02 16:00:00    3
2014-01-03 00:00:00    1
2014-01-03 08:00:00    1
2014-01-03 16:00:00    5
2014-01-04 00:00:00    1
```

**Output after** `pandas rolling`

```
series.rolling('D', min_periods=1).min()

2014-01-01 00:00:00    5.0
2014-01-01 08:00:00    3.0
2014-01-01 16:00:00    3.0
2014-01-02 00:00:00    3.0
2014-01-02 08:00:00    1.0
2014-01-02 16:00:00    1.0
2014-01-03 00:00:00    1.0
2014-01-03 08:00:00    1.0
2014-01-03 16:00:00    1.0
2014-01-04 00:00:00    1.0
```

**Desired output** (reset each day)

I can get the desired output like this but want to avoid looping:

```
series_list = []
for i in set(series.index.date):
    series_list.append(series.loc[str(i)].rolling('D', min_periods=1).min())
pd.concat(series_list).sort_index()

2014-01-01 00:00:00    5.0
2014-01-01 08:00:00    3.0
2014-01-01 16:00:00    3.0
2014-01-02 00:00:00    5.0
2014-01-02 08:00:00    1.0
2014-01-02 16:00:00    1.0
2014-01-03 00:00:00    1.0
2014-01-03 08:00:00    1.0
2014-01-03 16:00:00    1.0
2014-01-04 00:00:00    1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
series.groupby(series.index.date).cummin()
```

Output:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00    5
2014-01-01 08:00:00    3
2014-01-01 16:00:00    3
2014-01-02 00:00:00    5
2014-01-02 08:00:00    1
2014-01-02 16:00:00    1
2014-01-03 00:00:00    1
2014-01-03 08:00:00    1
2014-01-03 16:00:00    1
2014-01-04 00:00:00    1
Freq: 8H, dtype: int64
```